# How to refactor sequential ifs?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I wrote this code. It's really ugly. I would like to refactor it. I MUST return a `object[]`. I was thinking maybe using a `bool` value to check if I have to move forward calling other methods and just having the final `object[]` creation.

```
private object[] TrasferisciSingoloFile(some parameters...)
{
    Result result = new Result;

    result = FTPRename(some parameters...);
    if (result.error)
    {
        result.SetError("Some Problem 1");
        object tip = new object[] { par as ThreadCounterManager, result };
        return (object[])tip;
    }

    result = FTPDownloadAndCopy(some parameters...);
    if (result.error)
    {
        result.SetError("Some Problem 2");
        object tip = new object[] { par as ThreadCounterManager, result };
        return (object[])tip;
    }

    result = FTPMove(some parameters...);
    if (result.error)
    {
        result.SetError("Some Problem 3");
        object tip = new object[] { par as ThreadCounterManager, result };
        return (object[])tip;
    }

    result = FTPDelete(some parameters...);
    if (result.error)
    {
        result.SetError("Some Problem 4");
        object tip = new object[] { par as ThreadCounterManager, result };
        return (object[])tip;
    }

    object tip1 = new object[] { par as ThreadCounterManager, result };

    return (object[])tip1;
}
```

Comment: As per the code, at any point of time, either 1 if or none gets successfull.

May be, shoot a delegate call on all of these methods thus getting result[] from all of them (assuming all params are same). Then atleast 1 of the item in array shud be true w.r.t result.error. So ill call other method and return []. This will reduce your code from many ifs to may be 1 or 2.

Comment: But the exception would happen in the method call, and the assignment would never get to happen so result would be null, or the previous method's result.

Comment: True, But even in OPs code exceptions are not handled, so didnt think of it.

Comment: For starters, in no case do you need to cast tip.  It's already an object[]; you can simply `return tip`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let all the function of the suite FTPXXXX throw an exception when they found an error, so you can catch and return the error once in the `catch(){}` block. The "some problem xxxx message" can be decorated with a message you provide in raising the exception.

Comment: +1 one for the idea but I can't edit FTPXXXX, those methods are not mine. Basically the exception is handled inside FTPXXX and when I got an exception the variable result has the error field not empty

Comment: But exception way of solving a problem is good? I mean theres a performance pay we have to do right?

Comment: @Dierre so wrap all these methos in a class and raise the exception in the wrapped function

Comment: @zenwalker when you are facing a blocking error performance are no more an issue. Yes raising an exception is costly in term of time, but it must not affect the overall performance.

Comment: You can make wrapper functions that call the FTP functions that aren't yours. You would have control over those:)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your FTP functions are somewhere else in code, consider having them throw exceptions, and use a try/catch clause in this function.

```
Result result = new Result();
try
{
    result = FTPRename(some parameters...);
    result = FTPDownloadAndCopy(some parameters...);
    result = FTPMove(some parameters...);
    result = FTPDelete(some parameters...);
}
catch (SomeException e)
{
    return (object[])new object[] { par as ThreadCounterManager, result.SetError(e.Message) };
}

return return (object[])new object[] { par as ThreadCounterManager, result };
```

Comment: But the exception would happen in the method call, and the assignment would never get to happen so result would be null, or the previous method's result.

Comment: Agreed, the assignment would be skipped, so you get the latest "valid" result, plus the errormessage from where things went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the FTP methods, you could perhaps have them each assign the error message themselves, and make a helper method for creating the tip object. That way, you don't need to concern yourself with anything but checking to see if an error happened.

something like

```
private Object[] makeTip(arg1, arg2) {
    return Object[] {arg1, arg2};

}

Result result = new Result;

result = FTPRename(some parameters...);
if(result.error)
    return makeTip(par as ThreadCounterManager, result);

result = FTPDownloadAndCopy(some parameters...);
if(result.error)
    return makeTip(par as ThreadCounterManager, result);
...
return makeTip(par as ThreadCounterManager, result);
```